# How to include the JAR from another maven project in Maven

Tags: maven, module, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a fairly large project named: ProjectX. Inside this ProjectX folder we have a parent POM for the rest of the project. Project X has 2 Modules: ModuleA and ModuleB.

ModuleB is also a parent to two other Modules: SubModuleA and SubModuleB.

The issue I am running into is that SubModuleB requires the JAR that is generated from doing a "mvn install" on ModuleA, but I cannot figure out how to do this programatically in the POM without just copy/pasting the JAR from ModuleA into SubModuleB's resource folder.

Basically I want to be able to go straight to ProjectX's base directory and type "mvn install" and it goes through and generates the appropriate JARs and then I can just load them up in Geronimo or whatever without having to move anything around. Is what I am asking impossible?

Note I have tried using dependency but it doesn't seem to move the JAR into directory. Unless it actually does what I am asking and I'm not seeing it. :)

For reference (visually):

```
ProjectX - ModuleA
         \ ModuleB - SubModuleA
                   \ SubModuleB
```

edit: It turns out that if I run "mvn install" from ProjectX directory it does indeed copy/create the JAR in the M2_REPO location. And then when I run a "mvn eclipse:eclipse" I can see that the dependency is set properly for me inside of SubModuleB.

I hope this help future mvn noobs.

I will set this as an answer when I am allowed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I run "mvn install" from ProjectX directory it does indeed copy/create the JAR in the M2_REPO location. And then when I run a "mvn eclipse:eclipse" I can see that the dependency is set properly for me inside of SubModuleB.

I hope this help future mvn noobs.